# How to programmatically determine system device sound settings?

Tags: c#, audio, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I have to write a simple Silverlight app for WP7. If the phone is muted in system, the program must not play sounds, but if the phone is not muted the program must play sounds.

How to programmatically determine if Windows Phone is muted or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to do that, the system does not play any sounds when the phone is muted. The system setting overrides all other settings both in Silverlight and XNA (and in integrated Silverlight + XNA).

Comment: Hi Mika!
That is why I asked, when it is muted, Ringer toggle is switched off, I use a media element silverlight tag on the page, but the sounds plays. And it is annoying.

Comment: @VBalu987 the ringer and device volume settings are separate. switching the ringer to vibrate only does not set the device volume to zero. But setting the volume to zero will change the ringer to vibrate.

Comment: Did you run the volume all the way to 00/30 or just mute the ringer? Setting the volume to 00/30 mutes the whole system, muting the ringer does not affect media sounds etc.

Comment: H! Thank you for replying. Apologise, I don't know express myself properly. I don't know, that 00/30 is mute all the system sounds. The application has no sound, it is good. But, has any idea how to determine the state of ringer toggle button state? Thaks in advance.